# change date format while binding the data to the gridview

Tags: c#, date, gridview, binding, format

I want to change the format of the date while binding the value of the date to the gridview (02-oct-2019) like this

I have tried this :

```
Text='<%# Eval("InsertDateTime","{0:dd-mmm-yyy}") %>'

"this label is inside the gridview"

<asp:Label ID="lblInsertDateTime" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("InsertDateTime","{0:dd-mmm-yyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: What issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: it is getting time instead of Month name for eg : 01-49-2019

Comment: You should use `dd-MMM-yyyy`

Comment: oh thanks it is working now perfectly ...can you help me more with time also extending the same format

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings